# I intend to change only the font of a line using LaTeX Font Catalogue, but the whole of document will be changed

Tags: fonts

While I intend to change the font of only a line in the document using one of the fonts presented in the LaTeX Font Catalogue (https://tug.org/FontCatalogue/mathfonts.html) (for example, *concmath*: https://tug.org/FontCatalogue/computerconcrete/), but the font of the whole of document will be changed.

I do as follows:

```
\usepackage{concmath}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\newenvironment{concmath}{\fontfamily{concmath}\selectfont}{\par}

\begin{document} 
    The font of this text must be remained as it is by default.
    \begin{concmath}
            I want to change only the font of this line using one of the fonts in The LaTeX Font Catalogue.
    \end{concmath}
    The font of this text must be remained as it is by default.
 \end{document}
```

P.S. I am using LNCS as template and TeXstudio as editor.

Comment: [How do I use a particular font for a small section of text in my document?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/25249/172164)

Comment: @TivV  Thanks. Do you know where is a complete list, provided there for the Font family and Font name found ? for example, what is the Font family for the font "concmath"  ?

Comment: @Sverre , Yes, meanwhile, Ulrike Fischer's answer works as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look into concmath.sty you will find a line `\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{ccr}`. This gives you a clue about the family name of the font.

```
\documentclass{article}  % 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\newenvironment{concmath}{\fontfamily{ccr}\selectfont}{\par}

\begin{document}
    The font of this text must be remained as it is by default.
    \begin{concmath}
            I want to change only the font of this line using one of the fonts in The LaTeX Font Catalogue.
    \end{concmath}
    The font of this text must be remained as it is by default.
 \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It works. But, now another problem: after `\end{concmath}`, a new **paragrapg** is generated. How to continue in the same line after `\end{concmath}` ? Thanks

Comment: Don't use a `\par` in the environment if you don't want it (it was from your example).

Comment: Yes, I removed `\par` and it is now like this: `\newenvironment{concmath}{\fontfamily{ccr}\selectfont}` , but yet a new paragraph is created after `\end{concmath}` , strange!

Comment: there is no paragraph, but you should probably use {\ignorespaces} as the second argument.

Comment: Yes, it works. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I have extended your MWE so that it is compilable by adding `documentclass{article} as the first line.

```
% fontprob.tex SE 527806  local font change

\documentclass{article}  % added
\usepackage{concmath}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\newenvironment{concmath}{\fontfamily{concmath}\selectfont}{\par}

\begin{document} 
    The font of this text must be remained as it is by default.
    \begin{concmath}
            I want to change only the font of this line using one of the fonts in The LaTeX Font Catalogue.
    \end{concmath}
    The font of this text must be remained as it is by default.
 \end{document}
```

Processing this does typeset with a different font within the `concmath` environment while not changing fonts outside that.

However there were warning messages such as:

```
  LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `T1/concmath/m/n' undefined
  (Font)              using `T1/cmr/m/n' instead on input line 10.
```

Perhaps your problem is with the LNCS template (whatever that is and however you have used it) and maybe other code you haven't shared. GOM

Comment: Thank you. I’m going to test your code tomorrow and share the result here.